# How to store div content to DB with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my project, I want to store div content to DB. The content is like:

```
<span>name:</span><input type="text" id="inputid" value="John"><br />
```

So I chose innerHTML to fetch them successfully. And with Ajax, the content would be stored to DB.

Yesterday, I found that stripslashes() should be called to format the content, and it could be updated successfully.

But today  stripslashes() made nothing done. Here is my js code:

```
var slcId = $('#slcStNum').val();
var tmTgDvHtml=document.getElementById("timeTagDiv").innerHTML;
$.ajax({
    dataType:'html',
    type:"POST",
    url:"get_ajax_csc_div.php",
    data:{htmlCnt:tmTgDvHtml,slcId:slcId},
    success:function (data) 
    {
        alert("test");
    }
 });
```

Here is html code:

```
<div id="timeTagDiv"><span>name:</span><input type="text" id="inputid" value="John"><br /></div>
```

Here is get_ajax_csc_div.php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['htmlCnt']))
{   
 include("DB.php");
 $htcnt=stripslashes(".$_POST['htmlCnt'].");
 $sql="update IDC SET stprocess='$htcnt' where id='".$_POST['slcId']."';";
 $sel = $conn->exec($sql);  
 }
 ?>
```

I changed dataType:'html' to dataType:'json', but it failed again. Who can help me?

Comment: Any errors in your console ?

Comment: any errors ?? in the console

Comment: most probably it's because of the quotation marks aroung the $_POST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have your `_POST[]` superglobal surrounded by quotes, making it a string.

Change this

```
$htcnt = stripslashes(".$_POST['htmlCnt'].");
```

With this

```
$htcnt = stripslashes($_POST['htmlCnt']);
```

Comment: Also there is problem with insert query.. 
`$sql = "update IDC SET stprocess='$htcnt' where id= ' ".$_POST['slcId']." ' ";`

Answer (score 0):

change your `get_ajax_csc_div.php` to

```
include("DB.php");

if(isset($_POST['htmlCnt'])) {
    $htcnt = stripslashes($_POST['htmlCnt']);
    $sql = "update IDC SET stprocess='$htcnt' where id='".$_POST['slcId']."'";
    $sel = $conn->exec($sql);  
}
```